# bash command line process flow

Tags: bash

I use bash in such way:

```
vara="'%a %b'"

function f
{
  echo -n $# : "$@"
}
```

**1.**

```
f  $vara
```

*ouput:*

```
 2 : %a %b
```

**2.**

```
f "$vara"
```

*ouput:*

```
1 : '%a %b'
```

Can anyone explain why the first one produces that output?

Answer (score 1):

This is a great example of Word Splitting and why we are taught to always quote our variables.

See this [excellent write up](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) for more details